# How do I recommit database to Heroku after destroying DB in the Heroku dashboard

Tags: django, heroku, postgresql-9.3

I've built an app using Django etc. I ran into a whole bunch of problems with database on Heroku after accidentally pushing to production before running `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations` and `heroku run python manage.py migrate`.

I decided to just completely destroy the database currently on Heroku and want to recommit my app's models to heroku. My hope is to completely start from a clean slate.

I just want to make sure I do this correctly so I'm asking for clear instructions about how to recommit my app's database to Heroku after destroying the database in the dashboard.

Current error I get when I open my app online is:

```
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME or OPTIONS['service'] value.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you completely removed your database you'll have to provision another one. Assuming you are using Heroku Postgres¹, you can [do that using the Heroku CLI like so](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres):

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

Here we are asking Heroku to provision the `heroku-postgresql` add-on using the free `hobby-dev` tier. Modify as needed.

You can also [provision add-ons using the Dashboard if you prefer](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons#using-the-dashboard).

As part of the provisioning process, Heroku Postgres will automatically set a new `DATABASE_URL` for your app. As long as your project was using this variable before you deleted your old database, it should find the new database without requiring any changes.

---

¹If you were using a different database add-on the solution should be more or less the same. Provision a new instance of the add-on, let it set its environment variable, and if your app was using that variable before it should pick it up on its own.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful and clearly explained.